# extension_dir not being picked from PHP.INI: PHP 5.3.5 not getting configured on Apache 2.2.22 For Zend 1.11.11 on Windows Ultimate 7

Tags: php, windows, apache

I am trying to configure PHP 5.3.5, Apache 2.2.22, Zend 1.11.11 on Windows 7 Ultimate 64 Bit having Service pack 1. I have consulted many sites and have applied nearly all ideas but still cannot configure MySql adaptor for Zend. The PHP.INI file is not getting correctly configured because extension_dir need to direct to the correct location where the adapter dll are available and I get:

> ***The mysql driver is not currently installed***

Following are some actions that I have taken so far:

**Changes in HTTPD.CONF (Apache)**

```
LoadModule php5_module c:/PHP/php5apache2_2.dll
PHPIniDir "c:/php" - also tried, 'c:/php', c://php with upper case and backslashes combination too
    DocaumentRoot "E:/Personel/Mics/libraryprj/public/"
    <Directory />
        #Options FollowSymLinks ::commented out manually
        #AllowOverride None::commented out manually
        #Order deny,allow ::commented out manually
        #Deny from all ::commented out manually
        Options All
        AllowOverride All 
    </Directory>
    AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
    AddType application/x-httpd-php .phtml
```

**Changes in PHP.INI File**

```
extension_dir = "C:\php\ext"
extension=c:\php\ext\php_pdo_mysql.dll - out of desparation
extension=p_pdo_mysql.dll
```

List of miscellaneous things that I did after consulting may sites:

1. Copied all contents of PHP/EXT folder into Windows/System32
2. Copied PHP File to c:\Windows, c:\Windows\system32
3. Added registry key [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\PHP], value of IniFilePath=c:
   \php

The core problem is to make Apache pick the correct PHP.INI file so that if I make any changes there, they are reflected. As of now, I am trying to set extension_dir directory to load the `php_pdo_mysql.dll` but the correct PHP.INI wouldn't be found anywhere. Couldn't post PHPInfo screen shot becuase of restrictions on new accounts here.
Following is the result of phpinfo:

{

```
Build Date  Jan 6 2011 17:50:45
Compiler    MSVC6 (Visual C++ 6.0)
Architecture    x86
Configure Command   cscript /nologo configure.js "--enable-snapshot-build" "--disable-isapi" "--enable-debug-pack" "--disable-isapi" "--without-mssql" "--without-pdo-mssql" "--without-pi3web" "--with-pdo-oci=D:\php-sdk\oracle\instantclient10\sdk,shared" "--with-oci8=D:\php-sdk\oracle\instantclient10\sdk,shared" "--with-oci8-11g=D:\php-sdk\oracle\instantclient11\sdk,shared" "--enable-object-out-dir=../obj/" "--enable-com-dotnet" "--with-mcrypt=static"
Server API  Apache 2.0 Handler
Virtual Directory Support   enabled
Configuration File (php.ini) Path   C:\Windows
Loaded Configuration File   (none)
Scan this dir for additional .ini files     (none)
Additional .ini files parsed    (none)
PHP API     20090626
PHP Extension   20090626
Zend Extension  220090626
Zend Extension Build    API220090626,TS,VC6
PHP Extension Build     API20090626,TS,VC6
Debug Build     no
Thread Safety   enabled
Zend Memory Manager     enabled
Zend Multibyte Support  disabled
IPv6 Support    enabled
Registered PHP Streams  php, file, glob, data, http, ftp, zip, compress.zlib, phar
Registered Stream Socket Transports     tcp, udp
Registered Stream Filters   convert.iconv.*, mcrypt.*, mdecrypt.*, string.rot13, string.toupper, string.tolower, string.strip_tags, convert.*, consumed, dechunk, zlib.*

Zend logo This program makes use of the Zend Scripting Language Engine:
Zend Engine v2.3.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2010 Zend Technologies

PHP Credits
Configuration
apache2handler
Apache Version  Apache/2.2.22 (Win32) PHP/5.3.5
Apache API Version  20051115
Server Administrator    email@home.com
Hostname:Port   localhost:80
Max Requests    Per Child: 0 - Keep Alive: on - Max Per Connection: 100
Timeouts    Connection: 300 - Keep-Alive: 5
Virtual Server  No
Server Root     D:/Apache/Apache2_2_22
Loaded Modules  core mod_win32 mpm_winnt http_core mod_so mod_php5 mod_actions mod_alias mod_asis mod_auth_basic mod_authn_default mod_authn_file mod_authz_default mod_authz_groupfile mod_authz_host mod_authz_user mod_autoindex mod_cgi mod_dir mod_env mod_include mod_isapi mod_log_config mod_mime mod_negotiation mod_rewrite mod_setenvif

Directive   Local Value Master Value
engine  1   1
last_modified   0   0
xbithack    0   0

Apache Environment
Variable    Value
HTTP_HOST   localhost
HTTP_USER_AGENT     Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:13.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/13.0.1
HTTP_ACCEPT     text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE    en-us,en;q=0.5
HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING    gzip, deflate
HTTP_CONNECTION     keep-alive
HTTP_CACHE_CONTROL  max-age=0
PATH    c:\PHP;E:\OracleClient11GBase\product\11.2.0\client_1\bin;E:\Oracle-Client;C:\Program Files (x86)\PC Connectivity Solution\;C:\Program Files (x86)\AMD APP\bin\x86_64;C:\Program Files (x86)\AMD APP\bin\x86;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Google Apps Sync\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\80\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\90\Tools\binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\90\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\90\Tools\Binn\VSShell\Common7\IDE\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 8\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Google Apps Migration\;E:\Personel\Installations\Zend\ZendFramework-1.11.11\bin;
SystemRoot  C:\Windows
COMSPEC     C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe
PATHEXT     .COM;.EXE;.BAT;.CMD;.VBS;.VBE;.JS;.JSE;.WSF;.WSH;.MSC
WINDIR  C:\Windows
SERVER_SIGNATURE    no value
SERVER_SOFTWARE     Apache/2.2.22 (Win32) PHP/5.3.5
SERVER_NAME     localhost
SERVER_ADDR     127.0.0.1
SERVER_PORT     80
REMOTE_ADDR     127.0.0.1
DOCUMENT_ROOT   E:/Personel/Mics/libraryprj/public/
SERVER_ADMIN    email@home.com
SCRIPT_FILENAME     E:/Personel/Mics/libraryprj/public/phpinfo.php
REMOTE_PORT     49757
GATEWAY_INTERFACE   CGI/1.1
SERVER_PROTOCOL     HTTP/1.1
REQUEST_METHOD  GET
QUERY_STRING    no value
REQUEST_URI     /phpinfo.php
SCRIPT_NAME     /phpinfo.php

HTTP Headers Information
HTTP Request Headers
HTTP Request    GET /phpinfo.php HTTP/1.1
Host    localhost
User-Agent  Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:13.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/13.0.1
Accept  text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language     en-us,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding     gzip, deflate
Connection  keep-alive
Cache-Control   max-age=0
HTTP Response Headers
X-Powered-By    PHP/5.3.5
Keep-Alive  timeout=5, max=100
Connection  Keep-Alive
Transfer-Encoding   chunked
Content-Type    text/html

bcmath
BCMath support  enabled

Directive   Local Value Master Value
bcmath.scale    0   0

calendar
Calendar support    enabled

com_dotnet
COM support enabled
DCOM support    disabled
.Net support    not present in this build

Directive   Local Value Master Value
com.allow_dcom  0   0
com.autoregister_casesensitive  1   1
com.autoregister_typelib    0   0
com.autoregister_verbose    0   0
com.code_page   no value    no value
com.typelib_file    no value    no value

Core
PHP Version     5.3.5

Directive   Local Value Master Value
allow_call_time_pass_reference  On  On
allow_url_fopen On  On
allow_url_include   Off Off
always_populate_raw_post_data   Off Off
arg_separator.input &   &
arg_separator.output    &   &
asp_tags    Off Off
auto_append_file    no value    no value
auto_globals_jit    On  On
auto_prepend_file   no value    no value
browscap    no value    no value
default_charset no value    no value
default_mimetype    text/html   text/html
define_syslog_variables Off Off
disable_classes no value    no value
disable_functions   no value    no value
display_errors  On  On
display_startup_errors  Off Off
doc_root    no value    no value
docref_ext  no value    no value
docref_root no value    no value
enable_dl   On  On
error_append_string no value    no value
error_log   no value    no value
error_prepend_string    no value    no value
error_reporting no value    no value
exit_on_timeout Off Off
expose_php  On  On
extension_dir   C:\php  C:\php
file_uploads    On  On
highlight.bg    #FFFFFF #FFFFFF
highlight.comment   #FF8000 #FF8000
highlight.default   #0000BB #0000BB
highlight.html  #000000 #000000
highlight.keyword   #007700 #007700
highlight.string    #DD0000 #DD0000
html_errors On  On
ignore_repeated_errors  Off Off
ignore_repeated_source  Off Off
ignore_user_abort   Off Off
implicit_flush  Off Off
include_path    .;C:\php\pear   .;C:\php\pear
log_errors  Off Off
log_errors_max_len  1024    1024
magic_quotes_gpc    On  On
magic_quotes_runtime    Off Off
magic_quotes_sybase Off Off
mail.add_x_header   Off Off
mail.force_extra_parameters no value    no value
mail.log    no value    no value
max_execution_time  30  30
max_file_uploads    20  20
max_input_nesting_level 64  64
max_input_time  -1  -1
memory_limit    128M    128M
open_basedir    no value    no value
output_buffering    0   0
output_handler  no value    no value
post_max_size   8M  8M
precision   14  14
realpath_cache_size 16K 16K
realpath_cache_ttl  120 120
register_argc_argv  On  On
register_globals    Off Off
register_long_arrays    On  On
report_memleaks On  On
report_zend_debug   On  On
request_order   no value    no value
safe_mode   Off Off
safe_mode_exec_dir  no value    no value
safe_mode_gid   Off Off
safe_mode_include_dir   no value    no value
sendmail_from   no value    no value
sendmail_path   no value    no value
serialize_precision 100 100
short_open_tag  On  On
SMTP    localhost   localhost
smtp_port   25  25
sql.safe_mode   Off Off
track_errors    Off Off
unserialize_callback_func   no value    no value
upload_max_filesize 2M  2M
upload_tmp_dir  no value    no value
user_dir    no value    no value
user_ini.cache_ttl  300 300
user_ini.filename   .user.ini   .user.ini
variables_order EGPCS   EGPCS
xmlrpc_error_number 0   0
xmlrpc_errors   Off Off
y2k_compliance  On  On
zend.enable_gc  On  On

ctype
ctype functions     enabled

date

Warning: phpinfo() [function.phpinfo]: It is not safe to rely on the system's timezone settings. You are *required* to use the date.timezone setting or the date_default_timezone_set() function. In case you used any of those methods and you are still getting this warning, you most likely misspelled the timezone identifier. We selected 'Asia/Karachi' for '5.0/no DST' instead in E:\Personel\Mics\libraryprj\public\phpinfo.php on line 2
date/time support   enabled
"Olson" Timezone Database Version   2010.15
Timezone Database   internal
Default timezone    Asia/Karachi

Directive   Local Value Master Value
date.default_latitude   31.7667 31.7667
date.default_longitude  35.2333 35.2333
date.sunrise_zenith 90.583333   90.583333
date.sunset_zenith  90.583333   90.583333
date.timezone   no value    no value

dom
DOM/XML     enabled
DOM/XML API Version     20031129
libxml Version  2.7.7
HTML Support    enabled
XPath Support   enabled
XPointer Support    enabled
Schema Support  enabled
RelaxNG Support     enabled

ereg
Regex Library   Bundled library enabled

filter
Input Validation and Filtering  enabled
Revision    $Revision: 298196 $

Directive   Local Value Master Value
filter.default  unsafe_raw  unsafe_raw
filter.default_flags    no value    no value

ftp
FTP support     enabled

hash
hash support    enabled
Hashing Engines     md2 md4 md5 sha1 sha224 sha256 sha384 sha512 ripemd128 ripemd160 ripemd256 ripemd320 whirlpool tiger128,3 tiger160,3 tiger192,3 tiger128,4 tiger160,4 tiger192,4 snefru snefru256 gost adler32 crc32 crc32b salsa10 salsa20 haval128,3 haval160,3 haval192,3 haval224,3 haval256,3 haval128,4 haval160,4 haval192,4 haval224,4 haval256,4 haval128,5 haval160,5 haval192,5 haval224,5 haval256,5

iconv
iconv support   enabled
iconv implementation    "libiconv"
iconv library version   1.11

Directive   Local Value Master Value
iconv.input_encoding    ISO-8859-1  ISO-8859-1
iconv.internal_encoding ISO-8859-1  ISO-8859-1
iconv.output_encoding   ISO-8859-1  ISO-8859-1

json
json support    enabled
json version    1.2.1

libxml
libXML support  active
libXML Compiled Version     2.7.7
libXML Loaded Version   20707
libXML streams  enabled

mcrypt
mcrypt support  enabled
mcrypt_filter support   enabled
Version     2.5.8
Api No  20021217
Supported ciphers   cast-128 gost rijndael-128 twofish cast-256 loki97 rijndael-192 saferplus wake blowfish-compat des rijndael-256 serpent xtea blowfish enigma rc2 tripledes arcfour
Supported modes     cbc cfb ctr ecb ncfb nofb ofb stream

Directive   Local Value Master Value
mcrypt.algorithms_dir   no value    no value
mcrypt.modes_dir    no value    no value

mhash
MHASH support   Enabled
MHASH API Version   Emulated Support

mysqlnd
mysqlnd enabled
Version     mysqlnd 5.0.7-dev - 091210 - $Revision: 304625 $
Compression     supported
SSL     not supported
Command buffer size     4096
Read buffer size    32768
Read timeout    31536000
Collecting statistics   Yes
Collecting memory statistics    No
Tracing     n/a

Client statistics   
bytes_sent  0
bytes_received  0
packets_sent    0
packets_received    0
protocol_overhead_in    0
protocol_overhead_out   0
bytes_received_ok_packet    0
bytes_received_eof_packet   0
bytes_received_rset_header_packet   0
bytes_received_rset_field_meta_packet   0
bytes_received_rset_row_packet  0
bytes_received_prepare_response_packet  0
bytes_received_change_user_packet   0
packets_sent_command    0
packets_received_ok     0
packets_received_eof    0
packets_received_rset_header    0
packets_received_rset_field_meta    0
packets_received_rset_row   0
packets_received_prepare_response   0
packets_received_change_user    0
result_set_queries  0
non_result_set_queries  0
no_index_used   0
bad_index_used  0
slow_queries    0
buffered_sets   0
unbuffered_sets     0
ps_buffered_sets    0
ps_unbuffered_sets  0
flushed_normal_sets     0
flushed_ps_sets     0
ps_prepared_never_executed  0
ps_prepared_once_executed   0
rows_fetched_from_server_normal     0
rows_fetched_from_server_ps     0
rows_buffered_from_client_normal    0
rows_buffered_from_client_ps    0
rows_fetched_from_client_normal_buffered    0
rows_fetched_from_client_normal_unbuffered  0
rows_fetched_from_client_ps_buffered    0
rows_fetched_from_client_ps_unbuffered  0
rows_fetched_from_client_ps_cursor  0
rows_affected_normal    0
rows_affected_ps    0
rows_skipped_normal     0
rows_skipped_ps     0
copy_on_write_saved     0
copy_on_write_performed     0
command_buffer_too_small    0
connect_success     0
connect_failure     0
connection_reused   0
reconnect   0
pconnect_success    0
active_connections  0
active_persistent_connections   0
explicit_close  0
implicit_close  0
disconnect_close    0
in_middle_of_command_close  0
explicit_free_result    0
implicit_free_result    0
explicit_stmt_close     0
implicit_stmt_close     0
mem_emalloc_count   0
mem_emalloc_amount  0
mem_ecalloc_count   0
mem_ecalloc_amount  0
mem_erealloc_count  0
mem_erealloc_amount     0
mem_efree_count     0
mem_efree_amount    0
mem_malloc_count    0
mem_malloc_amount   0
mem_calloc_count    0
mem_calloc_amount   0
mem_realloc_count   0
mem_realloc_amount  0
mem_free_count  0
mem_free_amount     0
mem_estrndup_count  0
mem_strndup_count   0
mem_estndup_count   0
mem_strdup_count    0
proto_text_fetched_null     0
proto_text_fetched_bit  0
proto_text_fetched_tinyint  0
proto_text_fetched_short    0
proto_text_fetched_int24    0
proto_text_fetched_int  0
proto_text_fetched_time     0
proto_text_fetched_datetime     0
proto_text_fetched_timestamp    0
proto_text_fetched_string   0
proto_text_fetched_blob     0
proto_text_fetched_enum     0
proto_text_fetched_set  0
proto_text_fetched_geometry     0
proto_text_fetched_other    0
proto_binary_fetched_null   0
proto_binary_fetched_bit    0
proto_binary_fetched_tinyint    0
proto_binary_fetched_short  0
proto_binary_fetched_int24  0
proto_binary_fetched_int    0
proto_binary_fetched_bigint     0
proto_binary_fetched_decimal    0
proto_binary_fetched_float  0
proto_binary_fetched_double     0
proto_binary_fetched_date   0
proto_binary_fetched_year   0
proto_binary_fetched_time   0
proto_binary_fetched_datetime   0
proto_binary_fetched_timestamp  0
proto_binary_fetched_string     0
proto_binary_fetched_blob   0
proto_binary_fetched_enum   0
proto_binary_fetched_set    0
proto_binary_fetched_geometry   0
proto_binary_fetched_other  0
init_command_executed_count     0
init_command_failed_count   0
com_quit    0
com_init_db     0
com_query   0
com_field_list  0
com_create_db   0
com_drop_db     0
com_refresh     0
com_shutdown    0
com_statistics  0
com_process_info    0
com_connect     0
com_process_kill    0
com_debug   0
com_ping    0
com_time    0
com_delayed_insert  0
com_change_user     0
com_binlog_dump     0
com_table_dump  0
com_connect_out     0
com_register_slave  0
com_stmt_prepare    0
com_stmt_execute    0
com_stmt_send_long_data     0
com_stmt_close  0
com_stmt_reset  0
com_stmt_set_option     0
com_stmt_fetch  0
com_deamon  0
bytes_received_real_data_normal     0
bytes_received_real_data_ps     0

odbc
ODBC Support    enabled
Active Persistent Links     0
Active Links    0
ODBC library    Win32

Directive   Local Value Master Value
odbc.allow_persistent   On  On
odbc.check_persistent   On  On
odbc.default_cursortype Static cursor   Static cursor
odbc.default_db no value    no value
odbc.default_pw no value    no value
odbc.default_user   no value    no value
odbc.defaultbinmode return as is    return as is
odbc.defaultlrl return up to 4096 bytes return up to 4096 bytes
odbc.max_links  Unlimited   Unlimited
odbc.max_persistent Unlimited   Unlimited

pcre
PCRE (Perl Compatible Regular Expressions) Support  enabled
PCRE Library Version    8.10 2010-06-25

Directive   Local Value Master Value
pcre.backtrack_limit    100000  100000
pcre.recursion_limit    100000  100000

PDO
PDO support enabled
PDO drivers     no value

Phar
Phar: PHP Archive support   enabled
Phar EXT version    2.0.1
Phar API version    1.1.1
SVN revision    $Revision: 305584 $
Phar-based phar archives    enabled
Tar-based phar archives     enabled
ZIP-based phar archives     enabled
gzip compression    enabled
bzip2 compression   disabled (install pecl/bz2)
OpenSSL support     disabled (install ext/openssl)

Phar based on pear/PHP_Archive, original concept by Davey Shafik.
Phar fully realized by Gregory Beaver and Marcus Boerger.
Portions of tar implementation Copyright (c) 2003-2009 Tim Kientzle.

Directive   Local Value Master Value
phar.cache_list no value    no value
phar.readonly   On  On
phar.require_hash   On  On

Reflection
Reflection  enabled
Version     $Revision: 305605 $

session
Session Support     enabled
Registered save handlers    files user
Registered serializer handlers  php php_binary wddx

Directive   Local Value Master Value
session.auto_start  Off Off
session.bug_compat_42   On  On
session.bug_compat_warn On  On
session.cache_expire    180 180
session.cache_limiter   nocache nocache
session.cookie_domain   no value    no value
session.cookie_httponly Off Off
session.cookie_lifetime 0   0
session.cookie_path /   /
session.cookie_secure   Off Off
session.entropy_file    no value    no value
session.entropy_length  0   0
session.gc_divisor  100 100
session.gc_maxlifetime  1440    1440
session.gc_probability  1   1
session.hash_bits_per_character 4   4
session.hash_function   0   0
session.name    PHPSESSID   PHPSESSID
session.referer_check   no value    no value
session.save_handler    files   files
session.save_path   no value    no value
session.serialize_handler   php php
session.use_cookies On  On
session.use_only_cookies    On  On
session.use_trans_sid   0   0

SimpleXML
Simplexml support   enabled
Revision    $Revision: 302715 $
Schema support  enabled

SPL
SPL support enabled
Interfaces  Countable, OuterIterator, RecursiveIterator, SeekableIterator, SplObserver, SplSubject
Classes     AppendIterator, ArrayIterator, ArrayObject, BadFunctionCallException, BadMethodCallException, CachingIterator, DirectoryIterator, DomainException, EmptyIterator, FilesystemIterator, FilterIterator, GlobIterator, InfiniteIterator, InvalidArgumentException, IteratorIterator, LengthException, LimitIterator, LogicException, MultipleIterator, NoRewindIterator, OutOfBoundsException, OutOfRangeException, OverflowException, ParentIterator, RangeException, RecursiveArrayIterator, RecursiveCachingIterator, RecursiveDirectoryIterator, RecursiveFilterIterator, RecursiveIteratorIterator, RecursiveRegexIterator, RecursiveTreeIterator, RegexIterator, RuntimeException, SplDoublyLinkedList, SplFileInfo, SplFileObject, SplFixedArray, SplHeap, SplMinHeap, SplMaxHeap, SplObjectStorage, SplPriorityQueue, SplQueue, SplStack, SplTempFileObject, UnderflowException, UnexpectedValueException

standard
Dynamic Library Support     enabled
Internal Sendmail Support for Windows   enabled

Directive   Local Value Master Value
assert.active   1   1
assert.bail 0   0
assert.callback no value    no value
assert.quiet_eval   0   0
assert.warning  1   1
auto_detect_line_endings    0   0
default_socket_timeout  60  60
from    no value    no value
safe_mode_allowed_env_vars  PHP_    PHP_
safe_mode_protected_env_vars    LD_LIBRARY_PATH LD_LIBRARY_PATH
url_rewriter.tags   a=href,area=href,frame=src,form=,fieldset=  a=href,area=href,frame=src,form=,fieldset=
user_agent  no value    no value

tokenizer
Tokenizer Support   enabled

wddx
WDDX Support    enabled
WDDX Session Serializer     enabled

xml
XML Support     active
XML Namespace Support   active
libxml2 Version     2.7.7

xmlreader
XMLReader   enabled

xmlwriter
XMLWriter   enabled

zip
Zip     enabled
Extension Version   $Id: php_zip.c 305848 2010-11-30 11:04:06Z pajoye $
Zip version     1.9.1
Libzip version  0.9.0

zlib
ZLib Support    enabled
Stream Wrapper support  compress.zlib://
Stream Filter support   zlib.inflate, zlib.deflate
Compiled Version    1.2.3
Linked Version  1.2.3

Directive   Local Value Master Value
zlib.output_compression Off Off
zlib.output_compression_level   -1  -1
zlib.output_handler no value    no value

Additional Modules
Module Name

Environment
Variable    Value
ALLUSERSPROFILE     C:\ProgramData
AMDAPPSDKROOT   C:\Program Files (x86)\AMD APP\
APPDATA     C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Roaming
CommonProgramFiles  C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files
CommonProgramFiles(x86)     C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files
CommonProgramW6432  C:\Program Files\Common Files
COMPUTERNAME    FAMJAD-PC
ComSpec     C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe
FP_NO_HOST_CHECK    NO
lib     C:\Program Files\SQLXML 4.0\bin\
LOCALAPPDATA    C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local
NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS    4
OS  Windows_NT
Path    c:\PHP;E:\OracleClient11GBase\product\11.2.0\client_1\bin;E:\Oracle-Client;C:\Program Files (x86)\PC Connectivity Solution\;C:\Program Files (x86)\AMD APP\bin\x86_64;C:\Program Files (x86)\AMD APP\bin\x86;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Google Apps Sync\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\80\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\90\Tools\binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\90\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\90\Tools\Binn\VSShell\Common7\IDE\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 8\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Google Apps Migration\;E:\Personel\Installations\Zend\ZendFramework-1.11.11\bin;
PATHEXT     .COM;.EXE;.BAT;.CMD;.VBS;.VBE;.JS;.JSE;.WSF;.WSH;.MSC
PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE  x86
PROCESSOR_ARCHITEW6432  AMD64
PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER    Intel64 Family 6 Model 42 Stepping 7, GenuineIntel
PROCESSOR_LEVEL     6
PROCESSOR_REVISION  2a07
ProgramData     C:\ProgramData
ProgramFiles    C:\Program Files (x86)
ProgramFiles(x86)   C:\Program Files (x86)
ProgramW6432    C:\Program Files
PSModulePath    C:\Windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules\
PUBLIC  C:\Users\Public
SystemDrive     C:
SystemRoot  C:\Windows
TEMP    C:\Windows\TEMP
TMP     C:\Windows\TEMP
USERDOMAIN  WORKGROUP
USERNAME    FAMJAD-PC$
USERPROFILE     C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile
VBOX_INSTALL_PATH   E:\Oracle\VirtualBox\
windir  C:\Windows
AP_PARENT_PID   1600

PHP Variables
Variable    Value
_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"]    localhost
_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"]  Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:13.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/13.0.1
_SERVER["HTTP_ACCEPT"]  text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
_SERVER["HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE"] en-us,en;q=0.5
_SERVER["HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING"] gzip, deflate
_SERVER["HTTP_CONNECTION"]  keep-alive
_SERVER["HTTP_CACHE_CONTROL"]   max-age=0
_SERVER["PATH"] c:\PHP;E:\OracleClient11GBase\product\11.2.0\client_1\bin;E:\Oracle-Client;C:\Program Files (x86)\PC Connectivity Solution\;C:\Program Files (x86)\AMD APP\bin\x86_64;C:\Program Files (x86)\AMD APP\bin\x86;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Google Apps Sync\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\80\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\90\Tools\binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\90\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\90\Tools\Binn\VSShell\Common7\IDE\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 8\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Google Apps Migration\;E:\Personel\Installations\Zend\ZendFramework-1.11.11\bin;
_SERVER["SystemRoot"]   C:\Windows
_SERVER["COMSPEC"]  C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe
_SERVER["PATHEXT"]  .COM;.EXE;.BAT;.CMD;.VBS;.VBE;.JS;.JSE;.WSF;.WSH;.MSC
_SERVER["WINDIR"]   C:\Windows
_SERVER["SERVER_SIGNATURE"] no value
_SERVER["SERVER_SOFTWARE"]  Apache/2.2.22 (Win32) PHP/5.3.5
_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"]  localhost
_SERVER["SERVER_ADDR"]  127.0.0.1
_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"]  80
_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"]  127.0.0.1
_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]    E:/Personel/Mics/libraryprj/public/
_SERVER["SERVER_ADMIN"] email@home.com
_SERVER["SCRIPT_FILENAME"]  E:/Personel/Mics/libraryprj/public/phpinfo.php
_SERVER["REMOTE_PORT"]  49757
_SERVER["GATEWAY_INTERFACE"]    CGI/1.1
_SERVER["SERVER_PROTOCOL"]  HTTP/1.1
_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"]   GET
_SERVER["QUERY_STRING"] no value
_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]  /phpinfo.php
_SERVER["SCRIPT_NAME"]  /phpinfo.php
_SERVER["PHP_SELF"] /phpinfo.php
_SERVER["REQUEST_TIME"] 1340765338
_SERVER["argv"] 

Array
(
)

_SERVER["argc"] 0
_ENV["ALLUSERSPROFILE"] C:\ProgramData
_ENV["AMDAPPSDKROOT"]   C:\Program Files (x86)\AMD APP\
_ENV["APPDATA"] C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Roaming
_ENV["CommonProgramFiles"]  C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files
_ENV["CommonProgramFiles(x86)"] C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files
_ENV["CommonProgramW6432"]  C:\Program Files\Common Files
_ENV["COMPUTERNAME"]    FAMJAD-PC
_ENV["ComSpec"] C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe
_ENV
```

Comment: hate to ask...but did you restart apache after making config file edits?

Comment: Yes, many times, not only Apache but the OS too.

Comment: Solved it. The problem was on the windows. I replicated the whole environment on Windows Home edition and everything worked out. Something on the original windows box must have been wrong, could not identify the root cause there so moved on with the one that was working.